# Is there any way to have android developer guide offline?

Tags: android, android-developer-api

My internet fails a lot and I want an [android developer](http://developer.android.com) offline version. If you know any useful links please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download it using sdk manager

there is (documentation for android SDK) checkbox under every Android API version you want

Answer (score -1):

https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-chm-documentation/downloads

You can use this link to download offline library of android developer